# another solution for if function for less writing

Tags: c++, arduino

Hello I am looking for a solution to a function for writing less and clutering the code :D

The question is: is there another function or another use of IF function to write less code? because I will need to write from up to 50 line of IF functions

Adding a code of how I am doing it and is there another way of doing it because I need it seprate for function to work, I am getting values from mqtt and difrent value needs to be in memory of the program

```
if (TESTAS == 30 && soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  }
  else if (TESTAS == 29 && soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    }
    else if (TESTAS == 28 && soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    }
```

Comment: you do not need `soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS` in all 3 conditions.

Comment: Combine: `if (TESTAS >= 28 && TESTAS <= 30 && soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) { ... `

Comment: Ok thanks for letting me know that :)

Comment: wait, what's difference in your 3 snippet?

Comment: To answer the question asked: yes, there is certainly a way to replace this with a single `if` statement. Shouldn't be obvious to you that this is logically equivalent to `soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS && TESTAS >= 28 && TESTAS <= 30`? Then, all you then need to do is translate `TESTAS` to one of three value that get passed to `digitalWrite`, which is a simple lookup from an array. Mission accomplished!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  if (TESTAS == 30 && soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
  }
  else if (TESTAS == 29 && soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    }
    else if (TESTAS == 28 && soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) {
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    }
```

Has the same inner function:

```
    digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
     delay(5000);
     digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
```

So you could put that in it's own function to simplify to:

```
  if (TESTAS == 30 && soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) {
    myFunction();
  }
  else if (TESTAS == 29 && soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) {
    myFunction();
  }
    else if (TESTAS == 28 && soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) {
    myFunction();
}
```

Where myFunction is:

```
    void myFunction() {
       digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
       delay(5000);
       digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
    }
```

And then you can see that those three conditions are very similar:

```
if(soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) {
      if (TESTAS == 30) {
        myFunction();
      }
      else if (TESTAS == 29) {
        myFunction();
      }
      else if (TESTAS == 28) {
        myFunction();
    }
}
```

And then you can simplify again using the `||` or operator:

```
if(soilmoisturepercent == TESTAS) {
      if (TESTAS == 30 || TESTAS == 29 || TESTA == 28) {
        myFunction();
      }
}
```

Another option is to use the less than or greater than operator to compare a range, let's say if you wanted any `TESTAS` equal to or under 30. e.g.:

```
if (TESTAS <= 30) {
    myFunction();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a switch case.

```
switch(TESTAS){
    case 30:
         digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
         delay(5000);
         digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
         break;
    case 29:
         digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
         delay(5000);
         digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
         break;
    case 28:
         digitalWrite(LED_PIN, HIGH); // turn on led 5 seconds
         delay(5000);
         digitalWrite(LED_PIN, LOW);
         break;
    default:
         your_fuction();
    
}
```